# Rules for expanding a bash array

Tags: bash

According to my bash man page: `If the word is double-quoted ${name[@]} expands each element of name to a separate word`.

This usually leads to exactly the expected behavior:

```
$ a=("foo 1" "bar 2")
$ for i in "${a[@]}"; do echo $i; done
foo 1
bar 2
$ size(){ echo $#;};size "${a[@]}"
2
$ [ "${a[@]}" = "foo 1 bar 2" ]&&echo ok
bash: [: too many arguments
```

But sometimes it does not:

```
$ [[ "${a[@]}" == "foo 1 bar 2" ]] && echo ok
ok
$ case "${a[@]}" in "foo 1 bar 2") echo ok; esac
ok
```

In those cases it seems to get evaluated into a single string. - This makes sense, but is a bit surprising. - I expected it to be equal to `"foo 1" "bar 2"` and therefore cause a syntax error.

Is there a rule in which context it is evaluated which way? (I couldn't find the right section in the bash man page.)

Additional question: Is there a case in which `"${a[@]}"` is handled differently from `${a[@]}`?

Comment: Remove the `"` and use `${a[@]}` instead of `"${a[@]}"`.

Comment: `case ${a[@]} in "foo 1 bar 2") echo ok; esac` -> ok

Comment: Use `set -xv` to view how bash processes the commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No word splitting or glob expansion is performed for `[[`.

From [Bash FAQ](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/FAQ):

```
Since word splitting is not performed when expanding shell variables in all
operands of the [[ command, this allows users to quote patterns as they wish
when assigning the variable, then expand the values to a single string that
may contain whitespace.
```

Additionally, refer to [Word Splitting](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting):

- Word splitting is not performed on expansions inside Bash keywords such as `[[ ... ]]` and `case`.
- Word splitting is not performed on expansions in assignments. Thus, one does not need to quote anything in a command like these:

  - `foo=$bar`
  - `bar=$(a command)`
  - `logfile=$logdir/foo-$(date +%Y%m%d)`
  - `PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH ./myscript`

Answer (score -1):

The man page did say `to a separate word` and did not say `into one word`.  The a array `"${a[@]}"` is not the same thing as `"foo 1 bar 1"`.  This only returns 1 big string:

```
for i in "foo 1 bar 1"; do echo $i; done
```

Comment: Exactly, In the first example it gets evaluated into separate words. In the second example it gets evaluated into one single word. - That is surprising and the reason for the question.